# using spry in asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages, spry

I am using Spry menu bar in asp.net but the problem is that when i use the menubar js and the css alongwith the javascript to initiate the widget in a master page nothing happens on mouse over while when i use the same code in a simple .net page it works perfectly. Am i missing something. Please suggest. A menu should be used in master page but if spry menu does not work in master page this way then i might have to move the menu to internal pages which is obviously not a preferred way.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

asp.net master pages typically screw around with the id's of your elements i think, have a read of [this](http://www.asp.net/(S(sf10gzjodvrpce55el2p5cnk))/learn/master-pages/tutorial-05-vb.aspx)